# Explode Email List

Tags: php, arrays, explode

So let's say, I want explode email list and password.

If I input email list on textarea look likes :

- email1@domain.com:password
- email2@gmail.com:password
- email3@yahoo.com:password

etc

And when submit automatically output like this

- email1:password
- email2:password
- email3:password

I've tried some solutions but always error, Here's form for input email list :

```
<form name="postit" method="POST" action="">
  <textarea name="users" cols="60" rows="10">
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['users']))
    {
echo stripslashes($_POST['users']); 
    }
    ?>
</textarea>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="   Submit   " /></td>
</form>



<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['users']))
    {
        $users= $_POST['users'];
        $preArrUsers = explode("\n",stripcslashes($users));
        $arrUsers['u'] = array();
        $arrUsers['p'] = array();
        foreach($preArrUsers as $up)
        {
            $up = trim ($up);
            $up = explode(':', $up);
            $u = $up['0'];
            $p = $up['1'];
            $arrUsers['u'][] = trim($u);
            $arrUsers['p'][] = trim($p);
        }
    }
?>
```

any other solution for the above cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
$up = explode(':', $up);
$u = $up[0];
$p = $up[1];

$email = explode('@',$u); // this will remove @domain.com from email
$email = $email[0];
echo $email .":". $p;
```

**Output**

```
email1:password
email2:password
email3:password
```

Comment: Your regexp code will not work with all [valid email addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses).

Comment: @Jocelyn now it will work :D

Comment: From what I can see in your code, `$email` is an array, not a string

Comment: @Uby now its look perfect, thanks for pointing me

Comment: @SumitBijvani : great, thanks for solution :) , and for all that has been give solutions thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2):

Or this, in a simple way.

```
$u = $up[0];
$p = $up[1];
$u = explode('@',$u);
$u = $u[0];
```

And,

```
$arrUsers['u'][] = trim($u);
$arrUsers['p'][] = trim($p);
```

if you want an array as an output, or:

```
echo $u.":".$p;
```

if you want an echoed list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for username/email instead of your `$u = $up['0'];`:

```
list($u) = explode('@', $up[0]);
```